# google reCAPTCHA not working with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, recaptcha

I am trying to setup a google recaptcha for my website contact form. but it is not working for me. Please help.

My view page

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My_SITE_KEY" ></div>
```

Controller

```
public function send()
        {
          $this->load->library('curl'); 
          $this->load->library('session');
          $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
                    $recaptchaResponse = trim($this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response'));
                    $userIp=$this->input->ip_address();
                    $secret='Secret key';
                    $url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response;=".$recaptchaResponse."&remoteip;=".$userIp;
                    $response = $this->curl->simple_get($url);
                    $status= json_decode($response, true);
        if($status['success']){  

        $config = array(        
                  'mailtype' => 'html',
                  'charset'  => 'utf-8',
                  'priority' => '1'
                   );


       $this->load->library('email',$config); 


                  $from_email = "yy@demo.com"; 
                  $to_email = "xx@demo.co.in"; 


        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . $this->input->post('email'). "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>" . $this->input->post('message'). "</td></tr>";




         $this->email->from($from_email, 'demo'); 
         $this->email->to($to_email);
         $this->email->subject('Contact Info'); 
         $this->email->message($message); 
         $this->email->send()
         $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Success..!');
         redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);


}else{
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Error...! Google Recaptcha UnSuccessful');
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
}
```

I am always getting the flash message

> Error...! Google Recaptcha UnSuccessful

When I Print the response `print_r($response); exit;`

> { "success": false, "error-codes": [ "missing-input-response" ] }

Comment: remove `;` from `"&response;=".$recaptchaResponse."&remoteip;=".$userIp;`...

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence_Cherone. you saved me